# Что быстрее: сравнение через тег или через сам объект

Tags: unity3d

Впрочем весь вопрос в заголовке.
Что быстрее:

```
if (gameObject.tag == "Player")
```

или

```
if (gameObject == playerObject) //playerObject переменная типа GameObject
```

Comment: Экономия на спичках. Но сравнение объекта стабильнее, в отличие от строки, которая изменчива и в ней можно допустить ошибку.

Comment: Тут стоит начать с того, что эти сравнения делают разные вещи.

Comment: для справки: для сравнения по тегу есть метод `gameobject.CompareTag()`, который не аллоцирует. Еще желательно строку, которую в него передаете, сделать const или static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда у меня возникают подобные вопросы, я открываю проект для экспериментов (у меня такой есть) и просто пробую. Окей, провел 3 эксперимента: в циклах (по 1 млн, 2 млн и 5 млн итераций) сравнил по объектам и тегам.

Результаты:

1. По 1 млн

- Оба: < 1 секунды

2. 10 млн

- По объектам: < 1 секунды - 1 секунды
- По тегам: 4 секунды

3. 100 млн

- По объектам: 1-2 секунды
- По тегам: 43 секунды.

Мне кажется результат очевиден

4. Ради интереса заставил Юнити прогонять 1 млрд итераций.

- по объектам: 15 секунд
- По тегам: 6 минут 55 секунд

Мне кажется, результат очевиден